# Laravel HasManyThrough with onetomany and onetoone

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three entities as follow:

1. Person
2. Client
3. Region

Client has a person_id foreign key and a a region_id foreign key. Person can have many clients and each client belongs to a region.
I'm trying to get a person's list of clients and for each client their region using a single query in Laravel.
I've used HasMany relationship in person to get the clients and this works fine. I'm trying to use hasManyThrough method to query a person and get his clients and their regions but I can't get this to work!
My relationships are set as:

1. Person hasMany clients
2. Client BelongsTo Region
3. Person hasManyThrough(Client , Region)

but it seems system can't build the inner join needed and I get error as region.person_id doesn't exist!

Query code is:

```
$person = Person::with("clients")->get();
```

on Person I have:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Region::class, Client::class);
}
```

I've tried other combinations but nothing works. I'm following this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Thanks

Comment: Please can you show the code you've tried to use to load/query the user :)

Comment: Added the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is:

```
$person = Person::with(['client', 'client.region'])->get();
```

This is assuming you have the correct individual relations in each model.

But the hasManyThrough should be working as well, can you add to your question the output of $person?

Comment: Thanks! this worked, however I still like to know why hasManyThrough doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post here the value of $person with the 'hasManyThrough' ?

Comment: it doesn't work, that's the issue, I get exception complaining region.person_id doesn't exist!

Comment: Yes, but that exception is helpful in order to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `hasManyThrough(Client::class, Region::class);` if it's giving key error then define keys preciously. [Define keys in hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through-key-conventions)

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(Client::class, Region::class);
```

[Reference Link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow and report back.